# How can I get composer PSR-4 autoloader to autoload a class that is extending on to a class that was autoloaded?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

**Error Message**
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Core\Controller" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Simple_App\src\Controllers\LoginController.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Simple_App\src\Core\Router.php(38): require() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Simple_App\public\index.php(14): Core\Router->route('/Simple_App/pub...', 'GET') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Simple_App\src\Controllers\LoginController.php on line 7`

It seems like LoginController cannot extend to Controller but everything looks right to me?

```
namespace Controllers;

use Core\Controller;

class LoginController Extends Controller {
    // Code Stuff Here
}
```

Core is located in the same parent directory as the folder housing LoginController.php. My composer.json autoloader looks like this.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Core\\": "src/Core/"
    }
}
```

Here is my index.php page

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../src/Core/init.php';

use Core\Router;
$router = new Router();

$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$method = $_POST['_method'] ?? $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$router->route($path, $method);
```

Comment: Was the class added after Composer autoload was created? And if so, did you run `composer dump-autoload`? It won't load any classes added to your Core directory afterwards unless you dump the autoload through CLI

Comment: I found the issue. It was inside my Controller class. I wasn't declaring a property and err out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was inside of the class that LoginController was extending too, I had an undefined property and it was error out. You can't require a file and run it if it has syntax errors so make sure you don't have any.